# Expected argument of type "scalar"

Tags: symfony

I have to save a value at the time of registration form.
In the controller I had this:

```
<?php
$heritageBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($heritage)
    ->add('category', 'choice')
    ->add('designation', 'text')
    ->add('value', 'text');
$heritageFormBuilder = $heritageBuilder->getForm();
$request = $this->get('request');
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $heritageFormBuilder->bindRequest($request);
...
}
?>
```

I received this:

```
array(2) {
      ["form"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["category"]=>
        string(1) "4"
...
```

It did not work because **category** is a foreign key to another table type **HeritageCategory**
I therefore modified as follows for my value I received, the correct format is:

```
<?php
$request = $this->get('request');
if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
    $post = $request->request->get('form');
    $post['category'] = $em->getRepository('PrismeMigrationBundle:HeritageCategory')->find((int)$post['category']);
    $request->request->set('form', $post);

    $heritageFormBuilder->bindRequest($request);
}
?>
```

I value my many changes in my request:

```
["form"]=>
      array(4) {
        ["category"]=>
        object(Test\MonBundle\Entity\HeritageCategory)#427 (6) {
          ["id":"Test\MonBundle\Entity\HeritageCategory":private]=>
          int(4)
          ["parent":"Test\MonBundle\Entity\HeritageCategory":private]=>
          int(3)
          ["code":"Test\MonBundle\Entity\HeritageCategory":private]=>
          string(0) ""
          ["name":"Test\MonBundle\Entity\HeritageCategory":private]=>
          string(21) "Résidence principale"
          ["bg":"Test\MonBundle\Entity\HeritageCategory":private]=>
          int(4)
          ["bd":"Test\MonBundle\Entity\HeritageCategory":private]=>
          int(5)
        }
```

But I get this error:
**Expected argument of type "scalar", "Prisme\MigrationBundle\Entity\HeritageCategory" given**

What should I do as an amendment to the BindRequest is done correctly?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is going to solve the whole thing, but I hope it's a start...

Instead of:

```
$heritageBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($heritage)
    ->add('category', 'choice')
    ->add('designation', 'text')
    ->add('value', 'text');
```

Try:

```
$heritageBuilder = $this->createFormBuilder($heritage)
    ->add('category', 'entity')
    ->add('designation', 'text')
    ->add('value', 'text');
```

The "choice" type is designed for simple arrays of scalar information ("male"/"female", etc.). But "category" isn't scalar; it's a complete entity, and so the "entity" type makes more sense here.

Here are the docs on the entity field type:

http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/reference/forms/types/entity.html

Oh, and make sure HeritageCategory has a toString() method. The form will need that in order to render the labels.